# I can only see wallpaper and mouse Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, vmware, desktop-background

I have recently upgraded to windows 8.1 and since then its been problems and more problems. I used the VMWare image after the upgrade but after shutting down the virtual machine, all I have seen is a cursor and a background image.

All of my shortcut keys seems to work and also the menus on the side appears to be invisible as I can click blindly on the side and it launches whatever is meant to be on there like for example  Libre Office etc. I have also deleted the VMWare image with a fresh install from the ubuntu website but this doesn't change anything. I have also tried a couple of solutions from differnt websites but it doesnt seem to work for me.

Please help me as I am lacking at work

VMWare workstation 11.0
Ubuntu 14.04